# When and why to use a number as a String input?

Tags: java

I have been reading a java book where I came across a piece of code where a fake input is provided in order to test the main class. The fake input is a String and later converted into int primitive type using the Integer.parseInt() method. Following are the two classes:

The main class

```
public class SimpleDotCom{
    int[] locationCells;
    int numOfHits = 0;

    public void setLocationCells(int[] locs){
        locationCells = locs;
    }

    public String checkYourself(String stringGuess){
        int guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess);
        String result = "miss";

        for(int cell : locationCells){
            if(guess == cell){
                result = "hit";
                numOfHits++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(numOfHits == locationCells.length){
            result = "kill";
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The test class

```
public class SimpleDotComTestDrive{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SimpleDotCom dot = new SimpleDotCom();
        int[] locations = {2,3,4};
        dot.setLocationCells(locations);
        String userGuess = "4";
        String result = dot.checkYourself(userGuess);
    }
}
```

I tried the same example with an int variable and it worked:

```
public class DotCom{
    int[] locationCells;
    int numOfHits = 0;

    public void setLocationCells(int[] locs){
        locationCells = locs;
    }

    public String checkYourself(int stringGuess){
        //int guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess);
        int guess = stringGuess;
        String result = "miss";

        for(int cell : locationCells){
            if(guess == cell){
                result = "hit";
                numOfHits++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(numOfHits == locationCells.length){
            result = "kill";
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
}

public class DotComTestDrive{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DotCom dot = new DotCom();
        int[] locations = {2,3,4};
        dot.setLocationCells(locations);
        int userGuess = 4;
        String result = dot.checkYourself(userGuess);
        //System.out.println("result2 = "+result);
    }
}
```

I understand the code, but the question is why to have an input as a String where as the same result can be achieved by using an int variable.

I am not sure if I am missing something in understanding or may be my question is completely wrong, but as I tried the same example with an int variable and it worked, I keep wondering when and why to have inputs as a String?

Comment: Because I guess that it the real world, the user input will actually be... a user input, typed on the keyboard by a user, and wil thus be a string you'll have to parse.

Comment: You are only testing the "happy path". How do you test the scenario where the user enters `"arfle barfle gloop"` . ?

Comment: It can be useful if you want to keep leading zeros, but since that method immediately converts the input to `int` it would make more sense to require an `int` parameter in the first place. That shows that leading zeros are ignored anyway and works better regarding "single responsibility principle".

Comment: An example to the above is phone numbers, imagine if a phonenumber is "0000444455", if you stored it as an int it would just read as "444455", hence it is usually smarter to store phonenumbers as strings

Answer (score 4):

Internally in your program it is recommended to use the strongest possible type, in your case use the int.

But your program has an outside border where data come in and go out, like user input, feedback on the console, I/O operations to files or network, etc. In many cases you have to convert the involved data to or from types which are defined by the interface specification. An XML or json structure transports each data as a string, including numbers and dates. As soon as it passes the border of your application it should be immediately converted to the internally used type (and - of course - checked if the conversion is valid).

The background to this is: Serializing and deserializing (network streams, files) is easier done (better interchangable) using strings. But inside a process (by the CPU) it is better to operate on binary representations of the data.

Comment: I tend to disagree with regards to the de/serialization of objects. If you take a `String` representation of an object and try to de/zerialize it based on the `String` representation, this might proof to be quite hard. This is the reason why frameworks like [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) and [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) use reflection and annotations for de/serialization. In a real-world project, one would most probably use adapters, decorators, ... to add de/serialization capabilities.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The framework(s) do a lot of such helpful stuff like conversions and validations. But: My statement is still valid. The framework has to do quite the same things as you would do if you do not use a framework.

Answer (score 0):

**If the number is large enough and can't be inside the integer or long range.**

*Also, beneficial for solving these problems in an efficient way*

> 1) When you want to check if a number is a palindrome or not in an
>   efficient way.
>
> 2) When you want to know digits of the number without division
>   operator.

Few examples Which I am able to recollect now.

Comment: looking at the implementation (and especially the call to `Integer.parseInt(...)`), the given code does not "solve" the problem of big integers. If one acutally HAS a too large number, one should use constructs like [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: Yes BigInteger will definitely help

Comment: Or BigDecimal is even better.